# Bash - Getting output of a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

No matter what I seem to do, I can't seem to get the output of a command to be assigned to a variable in bash. Although my script runs find without any errors, I'm not getting the result I want:

```
# Prompt if the user needs Qt
echo ""
echo "Checking for qt5-default."
echo ""

OUTPUT="$(sudo dpkg -s qt5-default)"

echo "OUTPUT:"
echo $OUTPUT

...
```

`OUTPUT` will never echo anything. However, if I do:

`OUTPUT="$(ls -la)"`

Then it works. I'm wondering why.

---

Here is what I mean:

[image: Failure]

As you can see, the "OUTPUT:" string comes after the command output, which means that the output wasn't stored in the variable, but was run in the main shell, which confuses me.

Here is what happens when `OUTPUT="$(ls -la)"`:

[image: Success]

In this case, "OUTPUT:" comes before, showing that the `echo` command worked correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it is using standard error instead of standard output. Try `2>&1` at the end of the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OUTPUT=$( dpkg -s qt5-default 2>&1 )
```

Should do what you're after. As Etan pointed out, dpkg's output goes to stderr, not stdout.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -s` do not require root privileges. As good practice never use `sudo` inside of scripts, but require a root privileges for a script.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-sudo-command-inside-a-script

About your question: why it happens? Because `sudo` runs in sub-shell (brackets `$(...)` opens a subshell)

---

I will try to find a good reference about bash pitfalls and subshell, I don't remember where I read about it. Try this: [Subshell Pitfalls](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/gotchas.html)